# Почему поменялся ANDROID_ID и как получить прежнее значение?

Tags: java, android

Я использовал ANDROID_ID для идентификации пользователя на сервере.
Получал так:

```
sDeviseID = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), 
    android.provider.Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```

Сегодня в Android Studio обновился какой-то плагин и эта строка поменялась.
Причем, если я устанавливаю приложение из ранее сохранённого APK, показывается старая строка.
А если запускаю из отладчика Android Studio - получается другая.
В коде вообще ничего не менял. Телефон один и тот же.
Как вернуть старую строку?

Comment: Согласно доке https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Secure#ANDROID_ID дело может быть в ключе подписи приложения. Если у вас поменялся в студии дебажный ключ - то ничего, вроде, сделать нельзя, если старый ключ не достать (а он может быть уже просроченным). При этом для релизного ключа ничего поменяться не должно. Если же дело в обновлении версии ОС девайса, то в доке, вроде, есть какой-то способ достать старое значение из бэкапа какого-то. Ну и вообще не стоит это значение как ID использовать, т.к. оно, вроде, может поменяться и при сбросе к заводским настройкам.

Answer (score 1):

> Сегодня в Android Studio обновился какой-то плагин и эта строка поменялась.

Очень интересно было бы узнать, что это за плагин такой в студии, который влияет на работу Android системы...

`ANDROID_ID` уникален для устройств до *Android Oreo*. Начиная с *Android Oreo* используется связка **подписи программы и идентификатора**, в итоге `ANDROID_ID` будет уникальным для каждой отдельно взятой программы, а не устройства. Так же сброс данных устройства изменит `ANDROID_ID`.

Собственно, если у вас что-то не так, то проверьте подпись и имя пакета.